# Wordpress sitre redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, redirect

The website I am developing is acting up weirdly.
We have just transferred from local host to the actual server. However, when we tried to access it via the URL it automatically redirect from http://www.divinedcc.com to http://www.www.divinedcc.com 
which I have inspected in DB, .htaccess and wp-config.php, nothing seems wrong there.

Has anybody had this issue before? what's the best solution?

Thank you.

Comment: please check your database file and .htaccess file

Comment: I have checked it the URL is correct and .htaccess is what it is supposed to be. Even tho I disabled the plugins it is doing that.

Comment: ok can you send me your db file if possible

Comment: please download from here https://www.mediafire.com/?bjt38j7vj367gj7

Comment: ok thank you let me check

Comment: i have check your db file there is no issue

Comment: the only issue with redirection check your .htaccess file through out the site

Comment: set this in you wp-config file  define(‘WP_HOME’,’http://www.divinedcc.com’);
define(‘WP_SITEURL’,’http://www.divinedcc.com’);

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]  try to set this in .htaccess file

Comment: Both did not work. However, I tried to upload index.html on the same path as wordpress and tried to access. It did not work as well. Maybe it is from server config?

Comment: yes then check your root folder .htaccess file and ask your hosting provider for the same if problem exits there after

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: your welcome is your issue resolved